# Throw 404 page in Observer

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404, magento-1.9, observers

I've got an observer: `<controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view>` which triggers a function in my observer to check user restrictions.

If the customer is not allowed to view this category I want to show them the default Magento 404 error page. *This is where I am stuck at the moment.*

When I lookup the 404 page controller: `<Mage_Cms_IndexController>`
it shows me this forward to function "defaultIndex":

```
$this->_forward('defaultIndex');
```

which is this function:

```
public function defaultIndexAction()
{
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

But within my observer I cannot call the methods `loadLayout` and `renderLayout` which is quite obvious.

I do not want to use a 301/302 redirect to a 404 page, I want to show it directly to the user without any redirection.

**What I've got now:**

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
```

- I need to render the 404 page instead of the catalog layout, but how do I do this?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you got answer for this? I need to know How you managed this. Pleas post you answer

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER:**

I couldn't use `->_forward` straight away. It needs to be initialised first.

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');

$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$request->initForward()
    ->setControllerName('indexController')
    ->setModuleName('Mage_Cms')
    ->setActionName('defaultNoRoute')
    ->setDispatched(false);
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this without messing about with the request object, phew!

```
$exception = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception("404 THIS REQUEST");
$exception->prepareForward('norouteAction');
throw $exception;
```

That successfully went to my stores 404 page :)

The reason being is that it is picked up by the `catch` in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::dispatch` which handles a forward to the `norouteAction`

```
public function dispatch($action)
{
    try {
        $actionMethodName = $this->getActionMethodName($action);
        if (!method_exists($this, $actionMethodName)) {
            $actionMethodName = 'norouteAction';
        }

        Varien_Profiler::start(self::PROFILER_KEY.'::predispatch');
        $this->preDispatch();
        Varien_Profiler::stop(self::PROFILER_KEY.'::predispatch');

        if ($this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
            /**
             * preDispatch() didn't change the action, so we can continue
             */
            if (!$this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH)) {
                $_profilerKey = self::PROFILER_KEY.'::'.$this->getFullActionName();

                Varien_Profiler::start($_profilerKey);
                $this->$actionMethodName();
                Varien_Profiler::stop($_profilerKey);

                Varien_Profiler::start(self::PROFILER_KEY.'::postdispatch');
                $this->postDispatch();
                Varien_Profiler::stop(self::PROFILER_KEY.'::postdispatch');
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception $e) {
        // set prepared flags
        foreach ($e->getResultFlags() as $flagData) {
            list($action, $flag, $value) = $flagData;
            $this->setFlag($action, $flag, $value);
        }
        // call forward, redirect or an action
        list($method, $parameters) = $e->getResultCallback();
        switch ($method) {
            case Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception::RESULT_REDIRECT:
                list($path, $arguments) = $parameters;
                $this->_redirect($path, $arguments);
                break;
            case Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception::RESULT_FORWARD:
                list($action, $controller, $module, $params) = $parameters;
                $this->_forward($action, $controller, $module, $params);
                break;
            default:
                $actionMethodName = $this->getActionMethodName($method);
                $this->getRequest()->setActionName($method);
                $this->$actionMethodName($method);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```